# Excel VBA - how to populate a range with COUNTIF values that reference non-consecutive columns

Tags: vba, loops, excel, countif

Disclaimer: I realize that this is easy to solve by just forumlating the TALLY column within the table, but this is more of an exercise in learning VBA in general.

I have table in my worksheet that has multiple columns of "Yes" or No", and I would like to find a way in VBA to tally the No's in a separate column. Here is an example of what I am trying to describe:

[image: Example image]

I figure it involves a loop somehow which would include `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf`, but short of doing a really messy Union range to reference I cannot figure how to code this effectively. Thank you in advance for any ideas posited.

Answer (score 0):

Something like formula:

```
=COUNTIF(C:C,K1)+COUNTIF(F:F,K1)+COUNTIF(I:I,K1)
```

where K1 contains the value in C:C, F:F, and I:I that you want to count.

now if you need to count in ANY column you could just set the all the columns and do countif()
such as `=COUNTIF(A:I,K1)`  but any occurrence within A:I will be counted if Yes/No.

[image]

also note this is case insensitive.

Comment: Thank you, but I was hoping to do a `For Each` in VBA that I can add to my existing macro, that way it can help me learn more about Visual Basic's capabilities.

Comment: d'oh missed that part.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this (NOT with Countif):

```
Sub countCond()

Dim cond As String
Dim i As Long
Dim countCond As Long
Dim column As Variant

cond = "No" 'You can set this to 'Yes' as well

With Sheet1 'Or Worksheets("Sheet1") 'or whatever you have

    For i = 1 To .Range("TALLY").Cells.Count 
    'I suggest naming it (at least the sum column) 
    '--Edit: Without the header, so just the values.

        For Each column In .UsedRange.Columns 
        'Or maybe instead UsedRange, name the section 
        'that contains these columns

            If column.Cells(1).Value Like "*COMP" Then 'Assuming this is true

                If column.Cells(i + 1) = cond Then countCond = countCond + 1

            End If

        Next

        .Range("TALLY").Cells(i, 1).Value = countCond

        countCond = 0

    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

This way, your code manually counts the cond variable in every row for every column that looks like *COMP.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input, I believe I found an answer to my problem. Using this code I was able to get the results I wanted:

```
Sub Test()

Dim Fx() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim tg_row As Integer

Fx() = Array("Table1", "[EXAComp]", "[EXBComp]", "[EXCComp]")

For Each cl In Range("Table1[TALLY]")
    For i = 1 To 3
        If Range(Fx(0) & Fx(i)).Cells(tg_row, 1).Value = "No" Then
        cl.Value = cl.Value + 1
        Else: cl.Value = cl.Value + 0
        End If
    Next
    tg_row = tg_row + 1
Next cl

End Sub
```